# How can I stop my Mac opening jnlp files using Dashcode?

Tags: macos

My Mac has started opening jnlp files using Dashcode, rather than running Java. How can I fix this so it runs the files as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turns out to be as bizarre as it is simple.

[Open the folder /System/Library/CoreServices in the finder](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2009/Jun/msg00244.html)